build docker of COTS App running on Wind EC2
We have a COTS application running on an EC2 Windows server at AWS. This is a .net application that uses RDS Oracle DB as the back end. If we create an ami from the running EC2 instance, can we use it to create Docker? Would this work? Thank you for your help.

While you could tar the root volume of the AMI and import it into Docker as mentioned here, this approach creates a image with unnecessary OS components, kind of defeating Docker’s purpose of lightweight, efficient containers. Instead, I'd recommend refactoring the .NET application to work with a Dockerfile, which is well-documented.
